# Mongoid : How to query for array whose type of element is Integer by String?

Tags: mongoid

For example: I have Order record: `{id: 1, user_ids: [1, 2]}`

When the query condition is `String`:

`Order.in(user_ids: ["1"]).count #=> 0`

When the query condition is `Integer`:

`Order.in(user_ids: [1]).count #=> 1`

But I want to:

`Order.in(user_ids: ["1"]).count #=> 1`

Because the `user_ids` arrays contain a mix of numbers and strings.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? Does `user_ids` contain a mixture of strings and numbers?

Comment: Fix all of your `user_ids` arrays to only contain numbers, add any necessary validations and type cleanups to your models to ensure that they stay that way, and then query using numbers. Otherwise you'd have to search for both `1` and `'1'` all the time and that's an accident waiting to happen.